# Cramer's rule for finding the inverse of an $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Working off of [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Proof). I can understand all parts of the proof of cramer's rule, except for why $A_{ij} = 0$ for all $i \neq j$, where $A_{ij}$ denotates the $i$th row and the $j$th column if the matrix $A$. I was wondering if anyone could explain to me why that must be the case. If this is something which ought to be self-evident please point me towards a video or article which could educate me on the principles I am missing.

EDIT: the part i do not follow is the last sentence of the second paragraph of the proof section of the aforementioned Wikipedia article.

Comment: Can you point to the precise line or sentence where they use the statement which you don't follow? Skimming through the article I wasn't able to find what you're looking for.

Comment: It is because there are two repeated columns.

Comment: the part i do not follow is the last sentence of the second paragraph of the proof section.